# python - iterate through list whose elements have variable length

Tags: python, list, loops, iterator

How can I iterate through a list or tuple whose elements as lists with variable length in Python? For example I want to do

```
tup=( [1,2], [2,3,5], [4,3], [4,5,6,7] )
for a,b,c,d in tup:
     print a,b,c,d
```

and then have the elements of `tup` that are short to be completed with, say, `None`. I have found a workaround with the following code but I believe there must be a better way.

```
tup=( [1,2], [2,3,5], [4,3], [4,5,6,7] )
for a,b,c,d in [ el if len(el)==4 else [ el[i] if i<len(el) else None for i in range(4)] for el in tup ]:
     print a,b,c,d
```

Where `4` is actually the length of the "longest" element.

Is there a better way?

Comment: what are you doing with the values? Do you always need four values?

Comment: going to use them in `pyplot`. But each value is actually going to be a list.

Comment: `for a,b,c,d in ((vals+[None]*4)[:4] for vals in tup)` is shorter, but still not elegant

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To match your own output you can use [`izip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) to fill with `None`'s and transpose again to get back to the original order:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

tup=( [1,2], [2,3,5], [4,3], [4,5,6,7] )
for a,b,c,d in zip(*izip_longest(*tup)):
    print(a,b,c,d)
(1, 2, None, None)
(2, 3, 5, None)
(4, 3, None, None)
(4, 5, 6, 7)
```

If an `int`, `float` etc.. would be better then you can specify a different `fillvalue` argument to the `izip_longest` function:

```
tup=( [1,2], [2,3,5], [4,3], [4,5,6,7])
for a,b,c,d in zip(*izip_longest(*tup,fillvalue=0)):
    print(a,b,c,d)

(1, 2, 0, 0)
(2, 3, 5, 0)
(4, 3, 0, 0)
(4, 5, 6, 7)
```

Judging by your `print` statement you are likely to be using python2 but for anyone using python3 as @TimHenigan [commented below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30060671/python-iterate-through-element-variable-length/30060753#comment48236641_30060753) it is  [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest).

If you don't need a list you can use [itertools.izip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) which returns an iterator:

```
 from itertools import izip_longest, izip

tup = ( [1, 2], [2, 3, 5], [4, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7])
for a, b, c, d in izip(*izip_longest(*tup, fillvalue=0)):
    print(a, b, c, d)
```

Comment: For Python >=3, replace `izip_longest` with [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest).

Comment: very nice! Smart use of the `*` syntax. This is just what I had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3 we can do like this:

```
for i in tup:
    for j in i:
        print(j,"",end="")
    print()
```